# CSS style oveloading

Tags: html, css, overloading

[image: css overloading]

In this image I want to have #bf0018 as the value of the property colour

Can anyone help me ....

Comment: #bf018...?  That's not a color.

Comment: You could always try using photoshop. ;p It might be helpful to specify which editor you are using.

Comment: what do mean by that's not a color?chk it in your mspaint

Comment: it is #bf0018 not #bf018

Comment: colour...? That's not a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **don't** think you should use `!important`. Using `!important` will most likely mess up your styling in the long run. Instead read on css specificity. Two sources of information:

- [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)
- [smashingmagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

In your example can't you open typography.css and change the value? You shouldn't use `!important` as suggested in other answers.

Comment: !important will only mess up your styling if you misuse and abuse it.

Comment: and the first time you use it you are misusing it :). The only time I can see it suitable to use is when you don't control the markup, that is, it is delivered by some third party and you want to override some inline styling (which shouldn't exist). If you control the markup there is no need to use `!important`, just be more specific instead.

Comment: What's wrong with !important @Tomas? It could be a solution - based on the info Praneel gave us. Btw, I agree with your answer for a particular case. Css specificity is great if you're going to start a project from the scratch. If you have to manipulate something that already exists, and for example you need to override a prop, !important could be ok, no?

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree then. I much prefer using a few well-placed !importants instead of hugely specific selectors all over the place - they can turn into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I completely agree with Tomas Jansson.  The question needs to be edited with better information to support a correct solution.

Comment: and you don't think that the `!important` rule can turn into a maintenance nightmare? I really think if you are at a point when you feel you need to use `!important` you should look over your styling.

Comment: I agree with Tomas too. Using a{color: red !important;) will make ALL of your links red, no matter what CSS you use afterwards. Unless of course you use a better specificity, and you use html a{color: blue !imporant;}. If so, that is what you should be doing in the first place, just without the !important;

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand [CSS hierarchy](http://nzwhost.com/article/understanding-css-hierarchy). The file that  contains this color, must be below the other files that contains different color for the same class. If there are many color properties in the same file for the same class, then the the "correct" one must me the last, to override the rest. In case that you can't change file positions in the document, or you don't want to change the structure of css files, you can add [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) next the value like `.highlight {color: #bf0018 !important;}` but this is the last suggestion.

Comment: This is not true, the order only matters if they have the same specificity.

Comment: @Tomas three different files has the same property for the same class so the last will override the rest if there is no `!important` in the above files. What is wrong in this? In the screenshot above I see that all files have the same specificity.

Comment: he should be more specific instead, adding `!important` basically makes it much harder to work with later on.

Comment: as I wrote, this was my last suggestion. About specificity you are correct.

Comment: but the order is not really the case here, it could be that the rules are override due to specificity and not in which order the rules come.

Comment: @Sotiris: Also, the files doesn't have specificity. The file order only matters if the rules inside the files have the same specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Either load your TResWinIE stylesheet last so that the declaration comes last, or add !important to the rule in the TResWinIE stylesheet so it looks like so:

```
.highlight
{
   color: #bf0018 !important;
}
```

Comment: no, learn css specificity instead. `!important` will mess up your styling in the long run.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: There's no other answer to give, based on the tiny set of information given. And !important will only mess up your styling if used with reckless abandon - used sensibly, it's quite effective.

Comment: using !important is good for testing, if it isn't working with that, then you are doing something wrong. As Tomas said, never leave it there.

Comment: @danixd: finally one more that really don't think `!imporant` should be there :).

Comment: the order of when the files is not sure they matters, you have to take specificity into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) keyword to override all the other styles

Comment: !important isn't necessary unless you have inline styling added by a DOM script or if a control freak got hold of the markup.  It is better to understand the cascade and specificity. In this case where not enough information was offered to supply a proper solution, I'll have to agree though. :)

Comment: @mark123, great comment! But I don't understand what you're agreeing on.

Comment: What's wrong with !important @Tomas? It could be a solution - based on the info Praneel gave us. Btw, I agree with your answer. Css specificity is great if you're going to start a project from the scratch. If you have to manipulate something that already exists, and for example you need to override a prop, !important could be ok, no?

Comment: @steweb: I don't think so. If you are controlling the markup and css you can solve it by being more specific. I added a comment to my answer when I think you can use `!important`.

Comment: And what if i.e. you can't control the 'externally generated' HTML? what if i.e. you retrieve some external html templates from some ajax script? for a good use of css specificity you must have full control of both html and css. What if in this case the questioneer can just touch css? other solutions?

Comment: @Tomas Jansson, I actually don't agree with using !important.  The only reason I said that was because the original question didn't give enough information to offer a proper solution.  There is no way to determine specificity or cascade from the question.  First I would reorder the inclusion of the style sheets and then work on specificity if that has no effect.

Comment: @steweb: and that is what my comment on my answers says. if the markup is third party you basically have no other option, if not don't use it.